# Read data from HDFS

Tags: scala, hadoop, hdfs

I'm using the FSDataInputStream library to access the data from HDFS
The following is the snippet which I'm using

```
val fs = FileSystem.get(new java.net.URI(#HDFS_URI),new Configuration())
val stream = fs.open(new Path(#PATH))
val reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream))
val offset:String = reader.readLine() #Reads the string "5432" stored in the file
```

Expected output is "5432".
But the actual output is "^@5^@4^@3^@2"

Not able to trim "^@" since they are not considered as characters.Please help with appropriate solution.

Comment: Are you sure your file is stored as plaintext, not a sequencefile or some other format, for example?

Comment: Yep..it is stored as plain text only